# NHibernate and Criteria or NPersistence with other Query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would like to ask from some advice.
I usually use Java JPA with Criteria Queries and PostgreSQL in my projects (I work with Tapestry Framework which is based on Maven). I feel so comfortable with this tools and I can develop quickly. 
But now I must develop a proyect in C#. I have been studing similar tools in this platform and I have found NHibernate and NPersistence. The problem is that with NPersistence you can not use Criteria (http://www.npersistence.org/content/how-use-criteria), and with NHibernate you can not mapping with NPersistence. 
So, what do you thing could be more interesting for learn and quickly development?? May I use NHibernate with XML mapping and Criteria or could be better use NPeristence with another kind of queries??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate has some advanced Query options over Hibernate. QueryOver and Linq are compiler supported query languages.

For mappings Castle Active Record is similar to JPA Annotations. However FluentNHibernate and MappingByCode are IMO far better because they have the persistance ignorance like xml mapping but are far easier to use. They both also feature Automapping with conventions which are great.